# Dropwizard terminology for Rails engineers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, scala, frameworks, dropwizard

I recently started working with a team that uses  DropWizard(scala) + Jooq

I have experience with Rails.

I am wondering if someone familiar with both platforms can draw some parallels to dropwiazrd and rails terminology.

eg
active record
controllers
models
bundle
gemfile
routes
rake

Or point to some resources that cover this for rails engineers

Comment: I am also facing the same situation. ..:(

Comment: please upvote the question so that it becomes visible and eventually someone answers this

Comment: I too face the same issue here , Drop Wizard provides good documentation I follow that and compare it with rails and move on.  Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Yammer's slides on "[Dropping Rails For Dropwizard?](https://speakerdeck.com/bmorton/dropping-rails-for-dropwizard-from-abril-pro-ruby-2014)"

Slide 22 which contains all the parallels in terminology you need to know.

Slides 53-55 are also useful in highlighting which framework to pick for the right job.